# How to pass the object type in observable service in angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, object, observable, angular2-observables

I want to pass one object using BehaviorSubject variable and asObservable method.

So in shared crud.service.ts file I have declared this

```
private selected_element = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
selected_element_message = this.selected_element.asObservable();
changeselectedElement(status: {}) {
    this.selected_element.next(status);
    console.log("just selected this object",status);
    // here also I can also log the status object and it looks like this
    /*
    { 
        S.No:3
        metalid:"74"
        metalname:"Vfvfvfv"
        shortname:"Fvfvfv"
        __proto__: Object
    }   */
}
```

In one component where I am receiving object from frontend I am calling this in constructor.

```
public dataService:CrudService
```

and when I receive the object, I am pushing it like this.

```
this.dataService.changeselectedElement(ddata);
// here I can log the ddata and it looks like this. 

    /*
    { 
        S.No:3
        metalid:"74"
        metalname:"Vfvfvfv"
        shortname:"Fvfvfv"
        __proto__: Object
    }   */
```

where type of ddata is a simple object with keys and values.

on another component , I want to receive the object like this by subscribing to the service,

```
selected_element:any={};
 this.dataService.selected_element_message.subscribe(message => { 
 this.selected_element = message;

   console.log("Got the selected element", this.selected_element);
   // here I got the selected element as undefined...!
});
```

But I got the element as undefined, Earlier I have used the same above code for passing the array and it is working perfectly fine using this.

```
 private last_add_status = new BehaviorSubject<array>([]);
  last_add_status_message = this.last_add_status.asObservable();
  changelastAddStatus(status: array) {
    this.last_add_status.next(status)
    console.log("just added this array",status);
  }
```

Where is my mistake in this?

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue in the Plunkr?

Comment: Sorry I am not able to do it. but the issue is sorted, I was declaring the service at the wrong place as Luillyfe suggested. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here It works on perfectly , maybe it is about where you declare your service (you should do it on **app.module**):

[image]

[live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8r8xu?file=app%2Fanother.component.ts&devtoolsheight=50)

**app.module**

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [ AppComponent, AnotherComponent ],
  providers: [ CrudService ],
  ...
})
```